# Unable to re-render view in React Native project (functional component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am currently learning React.

After reading the docs and trying some examples, I still couldn't figure out how to make this code work:

### Issue:

View not re-rendering after data fetched/state changed.

The application loads an initially mocked data and then fetches the real data from the server, but despite fetching it correctly the view doesn't re-render as expected when using `setCdp`.

### Some points to consider:

1. All objects are correctly defined. Mock data renders correctly, no errors on the App.
2. All data is correctly arriving from the server. `console.log()` returns all the expected data.

---

### Expected behavior:

The view should be updated and re-rendered with the newly fetched data, replacing the old data with the new one.

### Code:

```
// Mock data declaration omitted...

export default function App() {
    const [cdp, setCdp] = useState(cardapio);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://ec*****.com.br/frontcontroller.php?file=getpratos.php')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((newState: Cardapio) => {
                setCdp({...newState}); // Doesn't seem to be working. Passing deep clone.
                console.log(newState); // Data is logged as expected.
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <CardapioPage cardapio={cdp}/>
            <StatusBar style="auto"/>
        </View>
    );
}
// StyleSheet "styles" also omitted.
```

**CardapioPage**

```
type Props = {
    cardapio: Cardapio
};
export const CardapioPage = (props: Props) => {
    const [cardapio, setCardapio] = useState(props.cardapio);
    return (
        <View>
            <CardapioView cardapio={cardapio}/>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Did you make sure your state is updated, console.log it before the render.
If the state is updated and passed to CardapioPage then the issue could be in the ChildComponent

Comment: The state is not being updated. Console.log() shows the fetched data but it never matches the state.

Comment: You shouldn't post the answer/solution in the question. you can create an answer and add your answer to it. best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating an `object` or `array` will not cause re-render usually, since they are reference values, adding some content to them will not cause re-render if the object does not **spread** in the `return` method with a higher-order function like `map`.

As a simple solution, you can add a `loading` state to your component to trigger a re-render on data arrive:

```
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [cdp, setCdp] = useState(cardapio);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    fetch('https://ec*****.com.br/frontcontroller.php?file=getpratos.php')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then((newState: Cardapio) => {
       setCdp({...newState}); 
     })
     .catch(console.log)
     .finally(() => {
       setLoading(false)
     })
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CardapioPage cardapio={cdp}/>
      <StatusBar style="auto"/>
    </View>
 );
}
```

Now, on component did mount, after an API call, in the `finally` method, the loading sets to `false`. changes on a state value will cause a re-render on your `App` component.

**Note:** You can set the initial state of your `loading` to `false`, but it causes an extra re-render on component did mount since in the `useEffect` the loading sets to `true` on the first trigger of `useEffect` on component did mount.

**Note:** Don't forget to use the `catch` method on your async API calls.

#### Update

You initialized the `cardapio` state value in `CardapioPage` page, so it gets the `props.cardapio` only once before `componentDidMount`, changes on the props will not cause change on your state variable, so this will cause the `<CardapioView cardapio={cardapio}/>` get same props.

There are solutions to solve issues, but as a simplest solution is to remove redundant `const [cardapio, setCardapio] = useState(props.cardapio);` from `CardapioPage`, and pass the props directly to the `cardapio`:

```
export const CardapioPage = (props: Props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <CardapioView cardapio={props.cardapio}/>
        </View>
    );
};
```

or, alternative:

```
export const CardapioPage = ({cardapio: Cardapio}) => (
  <View>
    <CardapioView cardapio={cardapio}/>
  </View>
);
```

If you really need the data to do some things, or change it, you can set your data on a `useEffect` hook:

```
export const CardapioPage = (props: Props) => {
   const [cardapio, setCardapio] = useState<Cardapio>();
   
    useEffect(() => {
      setCardapio(props.cardapio)
    }, [props.cardapio])

    return (
        <View>
            <CardapioView cardapio={cardapio}/>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: setLoading is also not changing values and the view is not re-rendering. There are no other errors around so now I'm clueless.

Comment: what is your expectation after re-render? the `CardapidoPage` component code is not available, please add this component snippet @Heizr

Comment: I'm expecting the App to re-render after the new data is fetched. 
I just edited the post if you'd like to check. @novonimo

Comment: I've updated my answer right now @Heizr

Comment: you can also remove the other components from your question, only the `CardapioPage` component shows the issues. @Heizr

Comment: Thanks, updated and It solved. @novonimo